# Text Align: Right in <span> or <div> (with HTML and C++)

Tags: c++, html, qt

I have following problem with this line

```
ui->tbChat->append("<span style=\"color: grey\">" + mynick[this] + "</span><span style=\"display: block; margin: 0px auto; text-align:right;\">" + getChatTime() + "</span><br><span>" + convertMessage(text) + "</span>");
```

[image]

I want to put the time in the right side, what for html code need for this, or what functionally?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code...

```
ui->tbChat->append("<span style=\"color: grey\">" + mynick[this] + "</span><span style=\"display: block; margin: 0px auto; float:right;\">" + getChatTime() + "</span><br><span>" + convertMessage(text) + "</span>");
```